# Android - Install debug version apk fail if building by gradle on Android 5.1.1 (But it's fine on Android 6.0.1)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a problem, a big problem for me!!!

Recently, I just move my project from Eclipse to Android Studio, and it works fine on Android 6.0.1(no mater debug or release version). However, for Android 5.1.1, only release version apk can be installed successfully. For debug version, the installation is always failed. Here are some messages from Logcat on Android 5.1.1:

```
04-01 20:36:21.617: E/installd(409): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/eu.amaryllo.cerebro-1/base.apk' --- status=0x0006, process failed
04-01 20:36:21.625: W/PackageManager(768): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/eu.amaryllo.cerebro-1
04-01 20:36:21.625: W/PackageManager(768): com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerException: scanPackageLI
04-01 20:36:21.625: W/PackageManager(768):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.scanPackageDirtyLI(PackageManagerService.java:6144)
04-01 20:36:21.625: W/PackageManager(768):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.scanPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:5451)
04-01 20:36:21.625: W/PackageManager(768):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installNewPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:10422)
04-01 20:36:21.625: W/PackageManager(768):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:10965)
04-01 20:36:21.625: W/PackageManager(768):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.access$2300(PackageManagerService.java:249)
04-01 20:36:21.625: W/PackageManager(768):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$6.run(PackageManagerService.java:8831)
04-01 20:36:21.625: W/PackageManager(768):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-01 20:36:21.625: W/PackageManager(768):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-01 20:36:21.625: W/PackageManager(768):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
04-01 20:36:21.625: W/PackageManager(768):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
04-01 20:36:21.625: W/PackageManager(768):  at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

I google this issue in a whole night, and still can not find an available way to fix it. Does anyone can help me? PLEASE...

If you need more information, just ask. PLEASE, VERY THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

Oh no!!! I find the problem by myself. In my project, there has a function which has 101 parameters. This will lead this issue. Change the way to pass arguments to this function, and then solve it. Thanks.

Comment: You saved my week. I had this same issue and the error thrown while installing was INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT but the debug logs vaguely mentioned the culprit method. I realized greendao had created a constructor with over 200 parameters. Switched to getters and behold, solved.